# Monitoring windows even log

Tags: powershell

Currently my script looks at the event logs for a entry with HP Smart Array and then the action is to send an email with the message. The issue is that if it detects an entry in the event log matching this description it will then return the message from the first event in the log which is usually completely irrelevant. Can someone suggest how to make the message be the message of the entry found for HP Smart array?

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $event = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName "system" -Newest 200

    if ($event.Source.Contains("HP Smart Array") -or $event.Source.Contains("disk")) {
        $body += Write-Output "Server $server has an error: " $($event.Message -split '\n')[0]  `n
    } else { 
        $body += Write-Output "Server $server has nothing to report           `n"
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your if statemant. It will check until the first entry matches. You need to loop throu all of your events. Change your code to:

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $events = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName "system" -Newest 200

    foreach ($event in $events) {
        if ($event.Source.Contains("HP Smart Array") -or $event.Source.Contains("disk")) {
            $Message += Write-Output "Server $server has an error: " $($event.Message -split '\n')[0]  `n
        }  
    }
    if ($null -eq $Message) {
        $Message = Write-Output "Server $server has nothing to report           `n"
    }
    $body += $Message   
}
```

Comment: I doubt that this will give sensible result. Each event with a source different from "HP Smart Arrray" and that doesn't contain "disk" causes a "Server ... has nothing to report". So you get probably 200 times "has nothing to report". I wouldn't like that.

Comment: That works really well thanks guys, one question is there a way to limit one response per server, as now we potentially get up to 200 lines from one server